# How to sort a list of dicts with numeric and alphabetic strings?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need help to sort my list of dicts.

```
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'code': '2'}, {'id': 2, 'code': 'b'}, {'id': 3, 'code': '1'}, {'id': 4, 'code': '10'}, {'id': 5, 'code': 'a'}]

import operator
my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('code'))
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 3, 'code': '1'}, {'id': 4, 'code': '10'}, {'id': 1, 'code': '2'}, {'id': 5, 'code': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'code': 'b'}]
```

I want to sort the list like that:

```
[{'id': 3, 'code': '1'}, {'id': 1, 'code': '2'}, {'id': 4, 'code': '10'}, {'id': 5, 'code': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'code': 'b'}]
```

I didn't see answer to sort it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the numerical strings to `int` (or `float`) for the sorting not to be lexicographic on the numerical strings. A simple way is defining a custom sorting function as:

```
def custom_sort(x):
    try:
        return 0, float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 1, x

my_list.sort(key= lambda x: custom_sort(x['code']))
```

---

```
print(my_list)

[{'id': 3, 'code': '1'},
 {'id': 1, 'code': '2'},
 {'id': 4, 'code': '10'},
 {'id': 5, 'code': 'a'},
 {'id': 2, 'code': 'b'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! And how to do when i have two codes for example : a_2 and a_10 ?

Comment: This seems like a different question @thomas which would require quite a different approach. I'd kindly encourage you to leave this question as is, and ask for this other specific case in a new separate question. Note that it's advisable to keep questions focused, otherwise it can confuse future visitors

Comment: I will create a new one ! Thank you !